# How do I configure Apache htaccess to allow access to a file on one domain and not another?

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, domain, .htaccess

I have a fairly default Apache install on Ubuntu 10.10. There's no virtual hosting and I would rather not add that. All domains that map to that machine are therefore served by the default site and the same directory.

What I would like is the .htaccess file in a specific directory to disallow access from a specific domain to that directory.

To clarify, xxx.foo.com/thefile.html gives a 403 (or whatever), but any other sub-domain or domain permits access to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like (untested and Rewrites never seem to work right the first time for me):

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  ^xxx.foo.com
RewriteRule  ^/thefile.html$  [FL]
```

This should cause the one file to be returned as "forbidden" on the matching domain. The `RewriteLog filename.log` is helpful in debugging rewrites. See the [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more on Rewriting.

Answer (score -3):

You can't do that without vHosting. If you can wait till 4pm eastern, I'll give you the code to do so. I'm not around my server now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know how to do virtual hosting if it's needed, it just affects my backup and costs me time. Surely, it's possible as a rewrite rule though?

Comment: This is definitely doable with mod_rewrite without using virtual hosting.